# Why are the inputs not being applied to the function in this MWE?

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction, scoping

Consider the following MWE

```
Clear["Global`*"]

randFunc[listFunc_] := RandomChoice[listFunc]@x;
mwe[list_] := Module[{testfun1, testfun2},
  testfun1[x_] = RandomChoice[list]@x;
  testfun2[x_] = randFunc[list];
  
  N@{testfun1[2], testfun2[2]}
  ];

mwe[{Sqrt, Log}]
```

Which gives output that looks like `{0.693147, Log[x]}`

The numbers/function changes because of `RandomChoice`, but **why does testfun1[2] evaluate but not testfun2[2]?**

---

Note: The following code (where the list is explicitly input in `testfun1` and `testfun2` does work

Clear["Global`*"]

```
randFunc[listFunc_] := RandomChoice[listFunc]@x;
testfun1[x_, list_] = RandomChoice[list]@x;
testfun2[x_, list_] = randFunc[list];
N@{testfun1[2, {Sqrt, Log}], testfun2[2, {Sqrt, Log}]}
```

Which gives output like `{1.41421, 0.693147}` (again, `RandomChoice` can change values, but they are both evaluating)

---

Note 2: I can get the expected behavior in the first example by changing `testfun2[x_] = randFunc[list] ;`to `testfun2[y_] = randFunc[list] /. x -> y;`, but I don't understand why I would need to do this.

Looking at the trace, Maybe `randFunc[list]` is not evaluating when `testfun2[x_]` is being defined in the `Module`, but I don't understand why this would be?

- (maybe the `HoldAll` attribute of `Module`?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the following:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
randFunc[listFunc_] := RandomChoice[listFunc]@x;
mwe[list_] := 
  Module[{testfun1, testfun2}, testfun1[x_] = RandomChoice[list]@x;
   testfun2[x_] = randFunc[list];
   Print[Information[testfun2]];
   N@{testfun1[2], testfun2[2]}];
```

where I put "Print[Information[testfun2]]" to actually see the definition of testfun2. If we now say:

```
mwe[{Sqrt, Log}]
```

[image: ...]

You see that the argument of testfun2 is localized, that mean its name is not "x" but "xDollar". Therefore, the x in Sqrt[x] is not replaced by "xDollar". Toward this aim, you must change your definition:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
randFunc[listFunc_] := RandomChoice[listFunc];
mwe[list_] := 
  Module[{testfun1, testfun2}, testfun1[x_] = RandomChoice[list]@x;
   testfun2[x_] = randFunc[list][x];
   Print[Information[testfun2]];
   N@{testfun1[2], testfun2[2]}];

mwe[{Sqrt, Log}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This answer is exactly what I was looking for. I had a feeling it had to do with something like this (and I noticed the `x$_` when using `Trace`) but I couldn't put everything together how I wanted.